# How to list all sub makefiles and call them using a loop

Tags: makefile

I am struggling to list all my Makefiles and call them from a master one..

I've got a directory of subprojects like this:

```
/awesome
  /john
    /doe
      Makefile
  /foo
    Makefile
  /bar
    Makefile
  Makefile (master one)
```

Let's say that each sub makefile looks like this

```
hell-yeah:
    echo HEY!
```

What i'd like to do is to search for all the submakefile, like this

```
SOURCES := $(wildcard **/Makefile)
```

Once i got them all, i'd like to run something like this `make awesome`

```
SOURCES := $(wildcard **/Makefile)

awesome: ## Run all submakefile hell-yeah rule
    for submakefile in $$SOURCES; do \
         $(MAKE) -C $$submakefile hell-yeah \
    done
```

How can I achieve it?

As of right now, I am getting the following error

```
for submakefile in $SOURCES; do \
         /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make -C $submakefile hell-yeah \
    done
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Thanks

Comment: You seem to be operating under the misconception that `make`'s is a *scripting* language.  It is not, and attempting to use it as if it were makes a mess.  `make` provides an alternative to shell scripting that makes sense in some cases, but not so much in others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write this shell script, or something like it:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

find * -mindepth 1 -name Makefile -print0 |
  sed -z 's,/Makefile,,' |
  xargs -0 -r -P1 -I{} make -C {} hell-yeah
```

That does rely on the GNU versions of the utilities used.  If relying on GNU versions is not acceptable then this variation does mostly the same thing, though it will trip over paths that contain blank or newline characters:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

find * -mindepth 1 -name Makefile -print |
  sed 's,/Makefile,,' |
  xargs -P1 -I{} make -C {} hell-yeah
```

Both of these assume that you will run them from the top directory (`/awesome`), and neither runs `make` in that directory itself, though that could easily be added.

You could embed either of those in a recipe in a makefile, but you shouldn't.  If you want to drive all these builds from a top-level makefile then that makefile should have an explicit enumeration of the project folders to build:

```
projects = \
  john/doe \
  foo      \
  bar

.PHONY: $(projects)

all: $(projects)

$(projects): %:
        make -C $@ hell-yeah
```

That does rely on features specific to GNU `make`.

Comment: Awesome answer, it helped me out a lot, thanks! However, at some point i'd like to call `hell yeah` but at some other point i'd like to call `iron man`. By following your answer, `make` will do the job, but is there a way to call make with params such as `hell yeah` or `iron man` to run different stuff (but again, over each directory from the enumeration). Hell yeah would call submakfiles with "hell-yeah" as param and Iron Man would call submakfiles with "iron man" as param

Thanks

Comment: @Emixam23, that's not what the question asked, but with either shell-script version, the script can accept the target to build as a positional parameter on the command line.  The simplest accommodation for that in either script itself would be just to replace `hell-yeah` with `"$1"`, though one could make it more complicated with default arguments, validation, *etc*, if one wanted to do.

Answer (score 2):

The following assumes that your directory names do not contain spaces (if they do don't use make at all for this project) and that you call make from the `awesome` directory.

There are 3 main issues:

1. I think `$(wildcard **/Makefile)` does not work as you expect. Try:

   ```
   SOURCES := $(shell find . -mindepth 2 -type f -name Makefile))
   ```
2. `$$SOURCE` in your recipe is wrong. It is the make variable that you want to expand, not a shell variable with the same name. Try to replace `$$SOURCE` with `$(SOURCE)`.
3. You want to `make -C DIR`, not `make -C DIR/Makefile`. Try to replace `$$SOURCE` with `$(dir $(SOURCE))`.

But looping over directories in a recipe, like you do, is not 100% make-ish. You could try:

```
SOURCES := $(shell find . -mindepth 2 -type f -name Makefile))
SUBDIRS := $(dir $(SOURCES))

.PHONY: awesome $(SUBDIRS)

awesome: $(SUBDIRS)

$(SUBDIRS):
    $(MAKE) -C $@ hell-yeah
```

We declare `awesome` and the directories as phony, declare the directories as prerequisites of `awesome`, and add the rule that *"builds"* the directories.

The main benefit compared with what you tried is the possibility to parallelize with `-j`.

Demo (outputs prefixed with `-|` ):

```
mkdir -p a/{1..2}
for m in a/Makefile a/{1..2}/Makefile; do printf 'hell-yeah:;\n' > "$m"; done
make -j
-| make -C a/ hell-yeah
-| make -C a/1/ hell-yeah
-| make -C a/2/ hell-yeah
-| make[1]: Entering directory '/Users/pacalet/tmp/a'
-| make[1]: 'hell-yeah' is up to date.
-| make[1]: Leaving directory '/Users/pacalet/tmp/a'
-| make[1]: Entering directory '/Users/pacalet/tmp/a/1'
-| make[1]: 'hell-yeah' is up to date.
-| make[1]: Leaving directory '/Users/pacalet/tmp/a/1'
-| make[1]: Entering directory '/Users/pacalet/tmp/a/2'
-| make[1]: 'hell-yeah' is up to date.
-| make[1]: Leaving directory '/Users/pacalet/tmp/a/2'
```